# change logo for multi language website in wordpress

Tags: wordpress-theming

I want to change my theme logo code and want to change my logo according to current language because my website is multi language in wordpress.
my code is as:

```
<?php
$logo = 'http://localhost/priyanka/wordpress_projects/Real_state/wp-content/uploads/2017/05/cropped-LOGO.png';
if( ICL_LANGUAGE_CODE == 'en' ) { // english
$logo = 'http://localhost/priyanka/wordpress_projects/Real_state/wp-content/uploads/2017/05/cropped-LOGO.png';
} elseif( ICL_LANGUAGE_CODE == 'fr' ) { // french
$logo = 'http://localhost/priyanka/wordpress_projects/Real_state/wp-content/uploads/2017/05/logo-f.png';
}
?>
<img src="<?php echo $logo; ?>" alt="Your Logo" />
```

but it can't work.can anyone have any idea please tell me.i am using GTranslator plugin.